# VPN и Интернет на одном компьютере

Tags: сеть, vpn

Есть пк с двумя сетевыми картами.

1 сетевая карта подключена к интернету через модем.

```
192.168.1.3
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.2
```

2 сетевая карта подключена к другому модему на котором настроен VPN

```
10.137.0.200
255.255.255.0
10.137.0.1
```

(`CE 172.55.137.1 PE 172.55.137.2` - не знаю нужно ли)

Вопрос: как сделать чтобы две сетевые работали одновременно?

Чтобы на этом пк был и интернет и VPN, а на всех остальных интернет. Пока работает только по отдельности.

Comment: А что сейчас не работает? Обычно простого подключения двух сетевых карт вполне достаточно, чтобы эти две сети нормально работали. Настраивать интернет на работу через VPN, разумеется, не нужно.

Comment: Могу разве что от балды предположить, что нужно не забыть прокинуть маршрут для подсети 10.137.0.0/24 на эту самую вторую сетевую карту, если вдруг он автоматически не добавился.

Comment: Если включить две сетевых карты одновременно, то перестаёт пинговаться  CE 172.55.137.1 и PE 172.55.137.2 Вернее выдаёт:Превышен срок жизни (TTL) при передаче пакета

Comment: Локалка и выход в интернет остаются, а VPN нет

Comment: А это кто такие, в какой сети находятся и почему должны пинговаться?

Comment: Это адреса выданные провайдером VPN для связи между PE и CE устройствами. Как я понимаю    CE адрес устройства на стороне клиента,а  PE адрес устройства на стороне оператора.

Comment: Мало что понял, но, наверно, вам нужно добавить в компьютере соответствующие маршруты для этих двух адресов, чтобы компьютер знал, что они относятся к VPN

Comment: Всё сделал. Всё было банально)).просто не был прописан постоянный маршрут.Спасибо .